# Balancing a PDE for Integration

Tags: integration, heat-equation

I'm stuck trying to understand a the mathematical step in a heat transfer texbook's example (found on Step 3 of .pdf Page 77 [here](http://web.mit.edu/lienhard/www/ahttv203.pdf)).  Re: Radial Heat Conduction in a Tube

The PDE is simplified to:

$$
\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial }{\partial r}\left ( r \frac{\partial T}{\partial r} \right )= 0
$$
We want to integrate to come to a conclusion, so I first try combining the left side of the equation :

$$
\frac{r}{r}\frac{\partial ^{2}T}{\partial r} = 0
$$

The first integral will give:

$$
r\frac{\partial T}{\partial r} = C_{1}
$$

The second integral is where I'm having trouble; naturally I'd want to say:

$$
\frac{1}{2}r^{2} = C_{1}r + C_{2}
$$

However, I think the book is saying :

$$
r \frac{\partial T}{\partial r} = C_{1} \rightarrow \frac{\partial T}{\partial r}=\frac{1}{r}C_{1}\rightarrow T=C_{1}\ln r +C_{2}
$$

Can someone help explain this to me?

PS - sorry - trying to format the math nicely now; it does look alright in the linked .pdf textbook.

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake is that $\frac{\partial^2 T}{\partial r^2}$ is not zero. You can multiply both sides by $r$ to get

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial r} \left ( r \frac{\partial T}{\partial r} \right ) = 0$$

but after that, the first integration gives

$$r \frac{\partial T}{\partial r}=C_1$$

so that

$$\frac{\partial T}{\partial r}=\frac{C_1}{r}.$$

Then you integrate again to get the logarithm.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I think there's a typo in the first part of your response (d/dr vs d/dT).  Then, I get confused about the nest step - wouldn't the first integral of the d/dr statement be r?  Thereby giving r^2 dT/dr =0  ?   I'm afraid my processing order is off here - I haven't done any integrals in a couple of years

Comment: @steve In the first integration, on the right side, the integral of $0$ is a constant. On the left side, the integral of the derivative of something is the something (again up to a constant).